# how to change namespace according to participant?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have 2 participants in my chain code and 1 transaction to change the ownership of 1 asset.
**.cto** file

```
asset Product identified by productId{
o String productId
--> User owner
}

abstract participant User {}

participant Buyer identified by buyerId extends User {
o String buyerId
} 

participant Seller identified by sellerId extends User {
o String sellerId
}
transaction changeOwner {
--> User user
--> Product product
} 

//script.js
async function change(tx) {
tx.product.owner = tx.user;
}'
```

The problem I am facing is while I am testing it in composer playground I can edit the transaction like

> "owner": "resource:org.example.basic.**Buyer**#buyer1", "owner":
>   "resource:org.example.basic.**Seller**#seller1"

If I follow this way the chain code is working fine but
When I am generating its angular skeleton and giving value it looks like this

> "owner": "resource: org.example.basic.**User**#buyer1"   even in APIs,
>   it is taking **User**

how can I make sure it sends correct Namespace or correct User??

Answer (score 0):

Composer playground models what you provide it, and gives suggested JSON for the modeled asset, participant or transaction etc. Its just a playground at the end of the day.

You need to pass the **resource** class into your transaction function, not the abstract class `User` (its not a resource registry where objects are stored or can be retrieved).

So your transaction should probably be (on the basis that the product owner ('owner') only, can 'sell' the asset :-) ) :

```
asset Product identified by productId{
  o String productId
  --> Seller owner
}

transaction changeOwner {
  --> Product product
  --> Buyer newOwner
}
```

and your transaction based on your current model:

```
//script.js
async function change(tx) {
tx.product.owner.sellerId = tx.newOwner.buyerId;
}
```

you should see the same thing in your Angular app.

Comment: Thanks Paul! yes I understood that concept. Actually, what I was seeking what if there are more that 5 participants and ownership just need to be change from one participant to another. In that case there need to be same number of transactions as number of participant while the functionality is same. I think there should be some way to achieve this. Hope you got my point.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question, as written: you would submit n-1 `changeOwner` transactions, so the ledger has a history of change of ownership.

Comment: Ledger might have the record but it'll not change the state of asset and it'll be contradict with ledger. So its of no use

Comment: hi Shubham, the asset (and its state) is also on the ledger FYI - so: history of the asset, and history of the transactions that affected it. HTH.

Comment: thanks paul for the explanation. can you comment on this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/52557576/9790416 ?